# tex4ht: scale for graphic doesn't work

Tags: graphics, tex4ht

I use tex4ht.

However when I include graphic, it includes with original size.
Scaling is ignored.

```
\documentclass[9pt,oneside,a4paper,english,notitlepage]{book} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{TestImage.png}
\end{document}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX in `dvi` mode, in which it is when `tex4ht` runs, doesn't support extraction of image dimensions for `png` or `jpg` images. This is because it supports only `eps` images. Because it doesn't know image dimensions, it can't scale them.

Fortunately, there is a way to find image dimensions. Try this command:

```
ebb -x TestImage.png
```

this will create file `TestImage.xbb`:

```
%%Title: ./TestImage.png
%%Creator: extractbb 20140317
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 300 300
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 300.000000 300.000000
%%CreationDate: Mon Jun  8 09:17:06 2015
```

you can read a `.xbb` file with `dvipdfmx` driver for `graphicx` package:

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[9pt,oneside,a4paper,english,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{TestImage.png}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{TestImage.png}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]